# Complex databinding issue

Tags: c#, wpf, polyline

Im trying develope a databound polyline canvas. 
Currently I databind a list of classes each containing an pointcollection and an offset. However I want to customize each of these lines further eg, their colour. Therefore I want to create a List inside the class containing a polyline model class. Which contain a pointcollection, offset X, Y and data for the polylines colour.

Currently it looks like this:

```
                <Canvas Name="PolyLineCanvas" Width ="100" Height="100">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WaypointList,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <Canvas/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=TracedPathLeft, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=TracedPathTop, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Polyline Stroke="Magenta" Points="{Binding TracedPath}" StrokeThickness="0.0244"></Polyline>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Canvas>
```

And class:

```
public class WaypointListModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public class Waypoint : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ObservableCollection<Waypoint> wptList;

        PointCollection tracedPath;
        double tracedPathTop;
        double tracedPathLeft;

        public Waypoint(ObservableCollection<Waypoint> WptList)
        {
            wptList = WptList;
        }

        public PointCollection TracedPath
        {
            get
            {
                return tracedPath;
            }
            set
            {
                tracedPath = value;
            }
        }

        public double TracedPathTop
        {
            get
            {
                return tracedPathTop;
            }
            set
            {
                tracedPathTop = value;
            }
        }

        public double TracedPathLeft
        {
            get
            {
                return tracedPathLeft;
            }
            set
            {
                tracedPathLeft = value;
            }
        }

        public void NotifyCanvas() //Method being called when pressing an update button
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TracedPathTop");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TracedPathLeft");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TracedPath");
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }

    ObservableCollection<Waypoint> waypointList = new ObservableCollection<Waypoint>();

    public ObservableCollection<Waypoint> WaypointList
    {
        get
        {
            return waypointList;
        }
        set
        {
            waypointList = value;

            NotifyPropertyChanged("WaypointList");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Here is the polylineModel class I made (similar to the one present upwards):

```
class WayPointPolyline : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    SolidColorBrush tracedPathColour;
    PointCollection tracedPath;
    double tracedPathTop;
    double tracedPathLeft;

    public SolidColorBrush TracedPathColour
    {
        get
        {
            return tracedPathColour;
        }
        set
        {
            tracedPathColour = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TracedPathColour");
        }
    }

    public PointCollection TracedPath
    {
        get
        {
            return tracedPath;
        }
        set
        {
            tracedPath = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TracedPath");
        }
    }

    public double TracedPathTop
    {
        get
        {
            return tracedPathTop;
        }
        set
        {
            tracedPathTop = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TracedPathTop");
        }
    }

    public double TracedPathLeft
    {
        get
        {
            return tracedPathLeft;
        }
        set
        {
            tracedPathLeft = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TracedPathLeft");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

However in the class called Waypoint

I want to replace PointCollection with:

```
        public List<WayPointPolyline > TracedPaths
        {
            get
            {
                return tracedPaths;
            }
            set
            {
                tracedPaths = value;
            }
        }
```

The xaml is where the hard part comes, since currently it adds only a single pointcollection per class addded in the List, what I need is a List where you add x classes, class x can contain data for y lines. Any idea what to do?

Thanks on advance!

Comment: What stops you from doing that & then adding new `ItemsControl` inside existing `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to Chris Eelmaa for the hint!

Xaml should look like this: I have not noticed any drastic difference in performance. However as an amatuer it would be interesting knowing if the code below is "too messy"

```
                <Canvas Name="PolyLineCanvas" Width ="100" Height="100">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WaypointList,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <Canvas/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TracedPathList,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <Canvas/>
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=TracedPathLeft, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=TracedPathTop, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                            <Polyline StrokeDashArray="{Binding TracedPathDashStyle}" Stroke="{Binding TracedPathColour}" Points="{Binding TracedPath}" StrokeThickness="0.0244"></Polyline>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Canvas>
```